# dvdauthor ERR: Can only have 128 commands for pre, post, and cell commands

Tags: dvd

I tried to make a DVD-Video of my favorite songs with a menu.

```
<vmgm>
<menus>
  <video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
  <audio lang="DE"/>
  <subpicture lang="EN"/>
  <!--************** MENU 1 **************-->
  <pgc entry="title">
    <button name="button01">g0=0;jump titleset 1 menu;</button>
    <button name="button02">g0=0;jump titleset 5 menu;</button>
    <button name="button03">g0=0;jump titleset 9 menu;</button>
    <button name="button04">g0=0;jump titleset 13 menu;</button>
    <vob file="/home/NTFS/DVD-VIDEO/tmp/dvd-tmp/menu0-0.mpg" pause="inf"/>
    <pre>g2=101;if (g0 == 3) { g0 = 2; jump title 2; }if (g0 == 4) { g0 = 2; jump title 3; }if (g0 == 5) { g0 = 2; jump title 4; }if (g0 == 6) { g0 = 2; jump title 5; }if (g0 == 7) { g0 = 2; jump title 6; }if (g0 == 8) { g0 = 2; jump title 7; }if (g0 == 9) { g0 = 2; jump title 8; }if (g0 == 10) { g0 = 2; jump title 9; }if (g0 == 11) { g0 = 2; jump title 10; }if (g0 == 12) { g0 = 2; jump title 11; }if (g0 == 13) { g0 = 2; jump title 12; }if (g0 == 14) { g0 = 2; jump title 13; }if (g0 == 15) { g0 = 2; jump title 14; }if (g0 == 16) { g0 = 2; jump title 15; }if (g0 == 17) { g0 = 2; jump title 16; }</pre>
  </pgc>
</menus>
</vmgm>
```

So, we have a list of 4 artists. Then we assign a menu of 4 songs to each artist in titleset. And one more song in this titleset.

```
<titleset>
<menus>
  <video format="pal" aspect="4:3"/>
  <audio lang="EN"/>
  <subpicture lang="EN"/>
  <!--************** MENU 1 **************-->
  <pgc entry="root">
    <button name="button01">g1=button;g0=2;jump title 1;</button>
    <button name="button02">g1=button;g0=2;jump titleset 2 title 1;</button>
    <button name="button03">g1=button;g0=2;jump titleset 3 title 1;</button>
    <button name="button04">g1=button;g0=2;jump titleset 4 title 1;</button>
    <button name="button00">g1=button;g0=0;jump vmgm menu 1;</button>
    <vob file="/home/NTFS/DVD-VIDEO/tmp/dvd-tmp/menu1-0.mpg" pause="inf"/>
    <pre>if (g2 &amp; 0xFFF == 1 and g1 gt 0) button = g1; else button = 1024;if (g2 &amp; 0x8000 !=0) {g2^=0x8000;if (g2==101) jump vmgm menu 1;}g2=1;</pre>
  </pgc>
</menus>
<titles>
  <video aspect="4:3"/>
  <audio lang="EN"/>
  <!--************** TITLE 1 **************-->
  <pgc>
    <vob file="/home/NTFS/DVD-VIDEO/tmp//dvd-cache/entry001.vob" chapters="0:00,0:30"/>
    <post>if (g0 gt 1) { g0 = 3; call vmgm menu entry title; }</post>
  </pgc>
</titles>
</titleset>
```

We place the remaining 3 artist's songs in separate sections below.

```
<titleset>
<menus>
  <audio lang="EN"/>
  <subpicture lang="EN"/>
  <!--************** MENU 1 **************-->
  <pgc entry="root">
    <vob file="/usr/share/dvdstyler/data/empty_pal_ac3.mpg"/>
    <pre>if (g2 &amp; 0x8000 !=0) {g2^=0x8000;if (g2==101) jump vmgm menu 1;}g2=1;jump vmgm menu;</pre>
  </pgc>
</menus>
<titles>
  <video aspect="4:3"/>
  <audio lang="EN"/>
  <!--************** TITLE 1 **************-->
  <pgc>
    <vob file="/home/NTFS/DVD-VIDEO/tmp//dvd-cache/entry002.vob" chapters="0:00,0:30"/>
    <post>if (g0 gt 1) { g0 = 4; call vmgm menu entry title; }</post>
  </pgc>
</titles>
</titleset>
<titleset>
<menus>
  <audio lang="EN"/>
  <subpicture lang="EN"/>
  <!--************** MENU 1 **************-->
  <pgc entry="root">
    <vob file="/usr/share/dvdstyler/data/empty_pal_ac3.mpg"/>
    <pre>if (g2 &amp; 0x8000 !=0) {g2^=0x8000;if (g2==101) jump vmgm menu 1;}g2=1;jump vmgm menu;</pre>
  </pgc>
</menus>
<titles>
  <video aspect="4:3"/>
  <audio lang="EN"/>
  <!--************** TITLE 1 **************-->
  <pgc>
    <vob file="/home/NTFS/DVD-VIDEO/tmp//dvd-cache/entry003.vob" chapters="0:00,0:30"/>
    <post>if (g0 gt 1) { g0 = 5; call vmgm menu entry title; }</post>
  </pgc>
</titles>
</titleset>
<titleset>
<menus>
  <audio lang="EN"/>
  <subpicture lang="EN"/>
  <!--************** MENU 1 **************-->
  <pgc entry="root">
    <vob file="/usr/share/dvdstyler/data/empty_pal_ac3.mpg"/>
    <pre>if (g2 &amp; 0x8000 !=0) {g2^=0x8000;if (g2==101) jump vmgm menu 1;}g2=1;jump vmgm menu;</pre>
  </pgc>
</menus>
<titles>
  <video aspect="4:3"/>
  <audio lang="EN"/>
  <!--************** TITLE 1 **************-->
  <pgc>
    <vob file="/home/NTFS/DVD-VIDEO/tmp//dvd-cache/entry001.vob" chapters="0:00,0:30"/>
    <post>if (g0 gt 1) { g0 = 6; call vmgm menu entry title; }g2|=0x8000; call menu entry root;</post>
  </pgc>
</titles>
</titleset>
```

We repeat the same for the remaining 3 artists. So we have a DVD with 16 songs. After adding an artist with 4 songs, we get an error. The same error if we will add a song for each artist. DVD file structure ends on 16-th item.

```
VIDEO_TS.BUP
VIDEO_TS.IFO
VIDEO_TS.VOB
VTS_01_0.BUP
VTS_01_0.IFO
VTS_01_0.VOB
VTS_01_1.VOB
...
VTS_16_0.BUP
VTS_16_0.IFO
VTS_16_0.VOB
VTS_16_1.VOB
```

How to make it fit 99 items?

Answer (score 0):

I've create

- TITLE menu with 11 items of artists
- 11 VMGM menus with items of songs
- 99 TITLESET with menu and song

Then insert commands

TITLE menu:
**jump to vmgm menu ARTISTNO**

VMGM menu of artist:
**jump to titleset TITLESET title 1**

Titleset TITLESET title 1:
**g0=1; call vmgm menu ARTISTNO;**

vmgm menu 1:
(pre commands) **if(g0==1){jump titleset 2 menu;} if(g0==2){jump titleset 3 menu;} if(g0==3){jump titleset 4 menu;} if(g0==4){jump titleset 5 menu;} if(g0==5){jump titleset 6 menu;} if(g0==6){jump titleset 7 menu;} if(g0==7){jump titleset 8 menu;} if(g0==8){jump titleset 9 menu;} (show menu)**

titleset (root) 2 menu 1:
**jump title 1;**

...